# Software to decide equality between expressions involving powers and trigonometry

Tags: mathematical-software

Given two expressions A and B involving integers, $\pi$, powers to rational exponents, and cosine, is there a software that determines if A = B? (Previous question asked A > B, but the bottleneck is equality.)

I am aware of the long-standing [sum-of-square-roots](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P33.html) problem in complexity theory. I am asking if there is a software implementation of a sound algorithm, which may take a long time or even not always terminate. As far as I know, standard math software, even if symbolic, resorts to decimal expansion to determine if A > B; but without mathematical guarantee.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "(slow) known algorithm".  If you know that $A \ne B$, then just use interval arithmetic.  The difficulty is getting a bound on how much precision you might need (and whether a reasonable amount suffices), but that's not an obstacle in practice.  Just increase the precision if it doesn't suffice, and in practice you'll get an answer with quite reasonable precision.  On the other hand, dealing with exact equality is much more algorithmically subtle, and there's no known algorithm that's even guaranteed to terminate at all without assuming Schanuel's conjecture.

Comment: I do need to decide exact equality. I didn't know about the conjecture you mention, and I am editing my question to clarify. Still, is there a sound algorithm which may work on specific instances?

Comment: You may want to try Wolfram|Alpha. I know that, for at least basic expressions, you can simply ask $f(x)=g(x)?$ and Wolfram|Alpha will output "True" or "False".

Comment: Input: cos(0) = cos(0.0000000000000000001)
Answer: TRUE
;-)

Answer (score 5):

I believe that what you are looking for is [MetiTarski](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Arith/index.html).  It is written (in part) by [Larry Paulson](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/), principal author of the theorem prover [Isabelle](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/hvg/Isabelle/).

Note also that Maple has an interval arithmetic package (**evalr**), which can also be used to show that certain inequalities are true.  Maple does **not** use 'raw' floating point arithmetic to decide exact problems - that would be horribly unsound.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers! Could you please elaborate on how to solve such problems in Maple? Maple would be much more convenient for me, as I don't need variables or boolean logic which may make MetiTarski a bit too complicated.

Comment: For deciding $A>B$, try evalr(Signum(B-A)).  This will evaluate the sign of B-A using interval arithmetic.  It can return 1, -1 or FAIL.  Or you can replace one of the constants in your expression by INTERVAL(c-eps..c+eps) and use evalr directly (but probably still on B-A).  You might need to use a high Digits setting for tricky (but solveable) cases.  Email me an example if this is not clear enough. 

Comment: I just tried evalr(signum(cos(1/2)^2 + sin(1/2)^2 - 1) and I got FAIL -- even with Digits := 2000; Is there a way to solve exactly this? Do you know if this would work with MetiTarski? My problems are quadratic polynomials in cos/sin in Pi (a/b) for integers a, b.

Comment: I meant Signum, not signum.

Comment: For deciding identities, you need to use entirely different techniques.  You cannot verify identities numerically (although you could show they are false that way).

Answer (score 2):

In Maple, you might try the probabilistic equivalence-tester **testeq**. For example:

> testeq(407-768*cos(1/5*Pi)-716*cos(1/7*Pi)-364*cos(11/35*Pi)-170*cos(1/35*Pi)+170*cos(6/35*Pi)+364*cos(4/35*Pi)-594*cos(9/35*Pi)+594*cos(16/35*Pi)+692*cos(2/5*Pi)+670*cos(2/35*Pi)+670*cos(12/35*Pi)-440*cos(3/35*Pi)-440*cos(17/35*Pi)+246*cos(8/35*Pi)-246*cos(13/35*Pi)-292*cos(3/7*Pi)+486*cos(2/7*Pi)=0);

true

EDIT: For trigonometric polynomials in rational multiples of $\pi$ with rational coefficients, equality can be checked algebraically. Let $x = \sum_{n=1}^n a_j \cos(b_j \pi/m)$ where $m$, $a_j$ and $b_j$ are integers, $0 \le b_j < 2m$. Then if $\omega=e^{i\pi/m}$ we have $x=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j(\omega^{b_j}+\omega^{−b_j})/2$. So $x=0$ iff the minimal polynomial of $\omega$, which is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_m(z)$, divides $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j (z^{2m+b_j} + z^{2m-b_j})$.

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful. Is there an implementation of testeq that is always correct but may take a long time?

Comment: testeq is by design probabilistic.  If it returns false, it is always correct, if it returns true, there is a very small chance it is wrong.  User beware.  For certainty, see my comments on my answer.


Comment: Thanks, but my question still stands. One can obtain a zero-error "testeq" by trying all random choices. Is this available somewhere? Also, I think this all boils down to bounding the distance from 0 of non-zero expressions -- are there bounds available for expressions involving cos/sin and powers? I am aware of Baker's work on logarithmic forms.

Comment: For trigonometric polynomials in rational multiples of $\pi$ with rational coefficients, equality can be checked algebraically.  Let $x = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \cos(b_j \pi/m)$ where $m$, $a_j$ and $b_j$ are integers, $0 \le b_j < 2 m$.  Then if $\omega = e^{i\pi/m}$ we have $x = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j (\omega^{b_j} + \omega^{-b_j})/2$.  So $x = 0$ iff
the minimal polynomial of $\omega$, which is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_m(z)$, divides $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j (z^{2m+b_j}+z^{2m-b_j})$. 

Comment: Thanks! This seems to solve basically what I asked, except I guess you can only handle integer exponents this way? It is also not hard to implement. If you make it an answer I'll accept it.